# How to optimize a Mongo Query to prevent timeout

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo query that takes a very long time to execute and most time it expires when using RoboMongo IDE

How can I rewrite  my query so that it is more efficient. I cannot put index on the DB because I don't own it.

Here my query

```
db.emp.find( 
{ 
    "people" : {$exists:true},
    "createdDate" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2020-01-01"), "$lte":ISODate("2020-12-31")},
    "people.theId" : {$exists:true},
    "people.systems.hasPay":{$exists:true},
    "people.systems.hasPay":true,
   
}).count()
```

Comment: A few steps that might help (assuming you have no indexes): 1. Move match queries that would result in a fewest results possible to top (perhaps `createdDate` could be the last match query); 2. Use `$project` to return only fields necessary for you; 3. Limit your results; 4. If issue still remains, split into several queries.

Comment: Thanks.. would you be able to expand on item 4.

Comment: What I meant is just a simple for loop (let's say, iterating 3 times) and with each you get a different group of results (for that to happen, you would also need to use `$skip` and `$limit` to avoid getting duplicate results).